# AMD 64 OS installation in Intel processer

Tags: 64-bit

I'm using Sony laptop with intel i3 (64bit) processor, i'm facing problem while installing amd-64 bit os, please help me to resolve this issue.

1. amd-64 bit os will support Intel (64bit) processor ?
2. I have Desktop with AMD athlon (64 bit) processor , if i install in this amd-64 bit OS is working , if i install same os in my laptop intel processor i'm not able to install.

please help me.

Answer (score 3):

It would be helpful if you could describe at what point you are having trouble installing (ie. can boot using liveDVD/liveUSB and start the install process but it stops at <> screen)

AMD x64 ISO should be fine with i3 x64 intel processor.

You can also try just booting from the liveDVD/liveUSB and trying out a few things.. open the file manager and browse some files, connect to your network and browse a few websites, try changing desktop background, etc). If these work ok then you should be fine.

Comment: There is a description of why and how to try Ubuntu before installing at this link, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389